# Create a unique list

Tags: python

I have written below python program to get unique list. But i want to reduce this code for same output. since python does not have break/continue outer loop, i could not reduce this count. could you please help how to reduce in some way.

```
empty_list=list()
length=int(input("enter the unique element length: "))
number=int(input("enter the element:"))

empty_list.append(number)
x=1 

while(x<length):
    z=0
    a=int(input("Enter the element:"))

    for y in empty_list:
        if(y==a):
            z=1

    if z==0:
        empty_list.append(a)
        x+=1 
    else:
        x=x

print(empty_list)
```

Comment: `empty_list` seems a misnomer.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to get user input and make a list of unique elements received?

Comment: Yes. above program doing what i am expecting. But i want reduce number of lines to achive same output.

Comment: Some feedback to your coding style:`z` appears to take the function of a bool, so you should declare it as such. Also give it a descriptive name. `empty_list` should also get a different name that describes what is contained.  `x=x` doesn't do anything. Leave a space before and after `=` signs.

Answer (score 2):

```
unique = list()
length = int(input("enter the unique element length: "))

while len(unique) < length:
    number = int(input("Enter the element:"))
    if number not in unique:
        unique.append(number)

print(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `list` use a set `set`. You don't need to check for uniqueness and can just create a `list` from the `set` at the end.

```
length=int(input("enter the unique element length: "))
number=int(input("enter the element:"))

number_set = set()
x=1 

while(x<length):
    z=0
    a=int(input("Enter the element:"))

    number_set.add(a)
    x = x + 1

print(list(number_set))
```

Comment: I do not want to use  "Set"

Comment: What if order matters?